# Extract all properties for Odata V2, when one condition is fulfilled.

Tags: xml, odata

Examle:

```
<feed xml:base="https://services.odata.org/Northwind/Northwind.svc/"
        xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/ado/2007/08/dataservices"
        xmlns:m=http://schemas.microsoft.com/ado/2007/08/dataservices/metadata
        xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2005/Atom">
  <title type="text">Customers</title> 
  <id>https://services.odata.org/Northwind/Northwind.svc/Customers</id> 
  <updated>2010-03-10T09:34:11Z</updated> 
  <link rel="self" title="Customers" href="Customers" /> 
  <strong><m:count>91</m:count></strong> 
  <entry>
    <id>https://services.odata.org/Northwind/Northwind.svc/Customers('ALFKI')</id> 
    <title type="text" /> 
    <updated>2010-03-10T09:34:11Z</updated> 
    <author>
      <name /> 
    </author>
    <link rel="edit" title="Customer" href="Customers('ALFKI')" /> 
    <link 
        rel="http://schemas.microsoft.com/ado/2007/08/dataservices/related/Orders"
        type="application/atom+xml;type=feed"
        title="Orders" href="Customers('ALFKI')/Orders" />
    <link 
  rel="http://schemas.microsoft.com/ado/2007/08/dataservices/related/CustomerDemographics"
  type="application/atom+xml;type=feed"
  title="CustomerDemographics" href="Customers('ALFKI')/CustomerDemographics" /> 
    <category term="NorthwindModel.Customer"
        scheme="http://schemas.microsoft.com/ado/2007/08/dataservices/scheme" /> 
    <content type="application/xml">
      <m:properties>
        <d:CustomerID>ALFKI</d:CustomerID> 
        <d:CompanyName>Alfreds Futterkiste</d:CompanyName> 
        <d:ContactName>Maria Anders</d:ContactName> 
        <d:ContactTitle>Sales Representative</d:ContactTitle> 
        <d:Address>Obere Str. 57</d:Address> 
        <d:City>Berlin</d:City> 
        <d:Region m:null="true" /> 
        <d:PostalCode>12209</d:PostalCode> 
        <d:Country>Germany</d:Country> 
        <d:Phone>030-0074321</d:Phone> 
        <d:Fax>030-0076545</d:Fax> 
      </m:properties>
    </content>
  </entry>
  <!-- <entry> elements representing additional customers goes here -->
  <strong><link rel="next" 
      href="https://services.odata.org/Northwind/Northwind.svc/Customers?
    $inlinecount=allpages&amp;$skiptoken='ERNSH'" /> </strong>
</feed>
```

In this case is CustomerID very unique and will only give one output, 
i would like to use that to extract all the customer information, such that I can parse it to my custom class.

I tried something like

```
        Console.WriteLine("End" + odata.Customers.Where(p=>p.d:CustomerID== "ALFKI"));
```

But that only returns that certain information, and not all the properties within this customer? 
Is this somehow possible?

Comment: `But that only returns that certain information, and not all the properties within this customer?` Which properties are returning and which are missing?

Comment: Only the customerID is being outputted. @Vinit

Answer (score 0):

You might want to add the C# tag too. 
You can look into XML deserialization, which would convert the entire XML document into an instance of an object.

Barring that, you can look into converting the document into an [XElement](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.xml.linq.xelement(v=vs.110).aspx), then use any variety of ways to get at the nodes.

[This article](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/concepts/linq/how-to-find-an-element-with-a-specific-child-element) has an example that you may be able to adapt with something like this (not tested):

```
XElement root = XElement.Load(xml);
IEnumerable<XElement> company =
    from el in root.Elements("m:properties")
    where (string)el.Element("d:CustomerId") == "ALFKI"
    select el;
foreach (XElement el in company)
        Console.WriteLine(el.ToString());
```

Also, please note that in my brief experimentation with your XML it appears to have invalid characters or something, so that will have to be dealt with as well.

Comment: It should though be possible using Odata connected services, since a custom class is already created for this purpose.